# How do I make textscan write NaN when it encounters a non-numeric value in a numeric column?

Tags: matlab

I have a csv with a number of columns, the second column is the only one with strings, as it names the variables. I open the csv with fopen and want to store it's contents in a cell with textscan. However, in the numeric columns there are a number of non-numeric values (errors), all with commas in them. I want textscan to write NaN in their place rather than just stop. This is what I have:

```
fileID = fopen(input,'r');
cell = textscan(fileID, '%n %s %n %n %n %n %n %n %n','Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',1,'ReturnOnError',false, 'EmptyValue',NaN, 'TreatAsEmpty','*,*');
fclose(fileID);
```

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Please post the screenshot of first few lines of your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your data looks like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
1,n1,1,1,fgd,1,1,1,1
2,n2,2,2,2,2,dfdf,2,2
3,n3,3,3,3,3,3,str1,223,,3
```

and you have no choice to change your data

- change the separator from comma to semicolon
- or surround the data with double quotes

`textscan()` can't be smart enough to detect that.
I would suggest an approach like:

```
fid = fopen('c.csv');
data = char(fread(fid))';
fclose(fid);
data = split(data);
```

now you can parse the data line by line (cell by cell).

```
{'col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9'}
{'1,n1,1,1,fgd,1,1,1,1'                        }
{'2,n2,2,2,2,2,dfdf,2,2'                       }
{'3,n3,3,3,3,3,3,str1,223,,3'                  }
```

or

```
fmt = '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s';
data = textscan(fid, fmt, ...
```

somewhere in your parsing loop you can use str2double which will result in `NaN` if it is not numeric:

```
>> str2double('str')

ans =

NaN
```